# Leaflet.markercluster cluster added to DOM event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to customize my marker clusters to appear as pie charts, using the Chart.js library.

I've overridden `iconCreateFucntion` to do the additional calculations necessary and set up my data, but to transform my icons into actual charts, I need to call some additional JS when the cluster icon is added to the DOM.

How can I hook into Leaflet.markercluster's "cluster icon added" event?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

It's as simple as adding something like:

```
cluster.on 'add', (event) ->
    # do stuff with event.target, which is the L.MarkerClusterGroup instance
```

to the `iconCreateFunction`

Hope this helps somebody else out one day...